# Memory leak in javascript and video-js on all browsers (with the simplest example)

Tags: javascript, html, video, memory-leaks, video.js

Update 2: already reported bug on video.js github. However, I still didn't find the cause of this bug. So this question remains open.

I have to say that those two who gave -2 are unreasonable and ignorable foolish people.

---

Update: I don't know who gave -1 to this question, especially he couldn't answer it.

I tried printing out all created new components and disoposed components of video-js.

I found that, after calling player.dispose, although most of the components, including the outer DIV, the inner VIDEO got disposed, there are some inner components, including 2 DIV, 3 LI, 2 BUTTON, and many SELECT are not disposed.

And I think those non-disposed elements keep in vjs.cache, and because the event listener callback (closures maybe) has dependency on context of the player object itself. So the main player is never disposed even the main DIV and VIDEO are removed from vjs.cache.

Specifically, the items not removed from vjs.cache includes:

```
1. DIV with contents: <ul class="vjs-menu-content"></ul>
2. Another DIV with contents: <ul class="vjs-menu-content"></ul>
3. LI with contents: subtitles off, captions off, and English
4. BUTTONs with contents: done and defaults
5. SELECTs with contents: 
5.1) <option value="">---</option><option value="#FFF">White</option><option value="#000">Black</option><option value="#F00">Red</option><option value="#0F0">Green</option><option value="#00F">Blue</option><option value="#FF0">Yellow</option><option value="#F0F">Magenta</option><option value="#0FF">Cyan</option>

5.2) <option value="">---</option><option value="1">Opaque</option><option value="0.5">Semi-Opaque</option>

5.3) <option value="0.50">50%</option><option value="0.75">75%</option><option value="1.00" selected="">100%</option><option value="1.25">125%</option><option value="1.50">150%</option><option value="1.75">175%</option><option value="2.00">200%</option><option value="3.00">300%</option><option value="4.00">400%</option>

5.4) <option value="none">None</option><option value="raised">Raised</option><option value="depressed">Depressed</option><option value="uniform">Uniform</option><option value="dropshadow">Dropshadow</option>

5.5) <option value="">Default</option><option value="monospaceSerif">Monospace Serif</option><option value="proportionalSerif">Proportional Serif</option><option value="monospaceSansSerif">Monospace Sans-Serif</option><option value="proportionalSansSerif">Proportional Sans-Serif</option><option value="casual">Casual</option><option value="script">Script</option><option value="small-caps">Small Caps</option>
```

I am still searching on how to remove them.

I just wonder why video.js, with its version up to 5.0.0, has never considered such memory leaks.

---

Original Question:

I have simply 2 buttons, 1 to add the video, and 1 to delete the video.

The video source is on my local machine, You can change the video source for your testing.

The source codes are as follows and easy to understand.

The problem of this code (with chrome memory snapshot) is that,

1. Initial: memory 5.5MB
2. When you click add, memory: 6.5MB (my video is about 800k-1MB per video)
3. When you click delete, memory: 6.3MB
4. When you click add again, memory: 6.8MB
5. When you click delete, memory: 6.7MB
6. When you click add again, memory: 7.0MB

and etc.

The memory just stacks up.

The video-js version is 4.12.7. I tried video-js 5.0.0 and there's no luck, it's same.

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code or what's wrong with video-js? How can prevent this leak?

Thanks.

```
<link href="/js/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/video-js/video.dev.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


<script>
function video_html(id) {
  return '<video id="video-js-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" ' +
  ' preload="auto" width="960" height="540"  crossorigin="anonymous" ' +
  'data-setup=\'{"example_option":true}\'>' +
  '\t<source src="http://192.168.101.1:20001/live/' + id + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> \n' +
  '\t\t<track id="video-vtt" kind="subtitle" label="english" srclang="en" src="http://192.168.101.1:20001/live/' + id + '.vtt" default></track>\n ' +
  '\t\t<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>\n' +
  '</video>';

};
var player;

var insertVideo = function(){
  console.log("insert video");
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    data:{},
    url: "http://192.168.101.1:20001/live/list", 
    success: function(list){
      keys = list["keys"];
      newest_key = keys[keys.length - 1];
      $("#video-container").html(video_html(newest_key));
      player = videojs("video-js-player", {}, function() {} );
    }
  });
};
 var removeVideo = function() {
       console.log("remove video");
       $('#video-container').html('');
       if (player) {
         player.dispose();
         player = null;
       }
     }



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      removeVideo();
    });

$('#add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  removeVideo();
  insertVideo();
});

});
</script>

<a id="add" href="#add">Add</a>
<a id="delete" href="#delete">Delete</a>
<div class="container" id="video-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Does completely destroying the DOM element then recreating it help at all?

Comment: Cache? [How to Completely Disable Cache in Google Chrome](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache)

Comment: Hi @Orpheus, if you mean the video-js-player DOM, I did remove it by calling .html('') on the container. Do you mean removing the container?

Comment: Hi @Ragdata, you have any idea where video-js saved this cache internally? I actually tried automatically clicking add and delete, after several hours, the browser will crash due to memory overflow (8G RAM machine).

Comment: Hi @Ragdata, thanks. I disabled cache as the link you provided, but it doesn't help.

Comment: How long after clicking delete have you waited? "Garbage collection" doesn't always happen straight away. Also, have you tried coding this without the video-js library - from what I can see you should be able to without any pain on your part - see if it makes much difference. I'd also try coding it without jqueery - that's more pain if you've come to rely on jqueery as a crutch for programming. By the way, I find having `To view this video please enable JavaScript` in an element injected via javascript highly amusing

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, chrome will force GC before the snapshot. And actually my browser crashes due to memory overflow after some hours of automatically clicking add/remove, so I am sure it is not problem of GC. I use video-js mainly because I need consistent subtitle/track features across different browsers. Without video-js, it is just a simple DOM substitution and I don't think there will be problem.  I think it must be somewhere inside video-js or I used video-js wrongly.

Comment: _I don't think there will be problem_ you think it's easier to look for a problem in an external library rather than quickly and easily determine if that library is the problem or not? Fair enough, you're probably right,. 90% of javascript libraries are pure bloated crap anyway

Answer (score 1):

I have located this bug, and submitted bug report to video-js. For more info, please read

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2686

Hope it helps to anyone who use video.js.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to clear existing memory before playing new video.

```
  if(this.player){
    for(let eventName of ['pause','play','ended','timeupdate']){
      this.player.off(eventName)
    }
  }
```